# Determine all prime, palindrome string integers within a range

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, primes, palindrome

I have written a program in Python 3x to determine all the prime, palindrome string integers in the range of two given numbers.

```
from math import sqrt

def check_prime(n):
    if n<2:
        return False
    for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n))+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    else:
        return True

for times in range(5):
    a,b = map(int,input().split())
    ct = 0
    for n in range(a,b+1):
        if str(n) == str(n)[::-1] and check_prime(n):
            ct += 1
    print(ct)
```

How can I make this program run faster, mainly optimizing my `check_prime` function so that it is faster than currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One suggestion: That `sqrt` is expensive, and you can eliminate it in a lot of common cases. For example: if any number except 2 is even, then it's not prime. Every second time you call `check_prime`, you're passing an even number.

So you can check `n%2` before the loop, and eliminate that `sqrt` on half of your calls. You can extend this to check the first few primes explicitly, before starting your loop:

```
def check_prime(n):
    if n<2:
        return False
    if n%2==0:
        return n==2
    if n%3==0:
        return n==3
    if n%5==0:
        return n==5
    for i in range(7, int(sqrt(n))+1, 2):
        if n%i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

You get diminishing returns by adding more checks. I benchmarked the above at about 2x as fast as your original code.

Comment: Don't forget about Memoization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). That speeds up the code when you run it multiple times. You can even save the pre-computed values to a file and load it using `eval`. In php, it would be something like `file_put_contents('primes.php','$primes='.var_export($primes));` to save and `include 'primes.php';` or `eval(file_get_contents('primes.php'));` to load it.

Comment: shouldn't that be `for i in range(7, int(sqrt(n)) + 1, 2)` to skip even numbers?

Comment: @Droogans yes, that's a good idea.